# Batch file with "access clearance"

Tags: batch-file

i have a very basic understanding of batch files, mainly because i am self-teaching. 
i am writing a batch file just for fun but what im wondering is if there is some way to make it so that, like for example...

```
`@echo off
:1
set /p log= password. 
if %log%==(predetermined-password-one-two-and-three) goto cl1
if %log%==(predetermined-password-four-five-and-six) goto cl2
```

(where if persons one, two, or three input their password, the bacth file goes to :cl1; and if persons four, five, or six input their password the batch file goes to :cl2; and so on and so forth...)

...that way i can determine what happens at :cl1, and what different happens at :cl2, in stead of determining what happens for each person.

any and all assistance is greatly apprreciated.

Comment: btw:
ignore the apostrphy before "@echo off"

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
@echo off
:1
set /p log= password. 
if "%log%"=="P_One" goto cl1
if "%log%"=="P_Two" goto cl1
if "%log%"=="P_Three" goto cl1
if "%log%"=="P_One" goto cl2
if "%log%"=="P_Two" goto cl2
if "%log%"=="P_Three" goto cl2

:cl1
Echo You are administrator...
set mode=A
goto start

:cl2
Echo You are Logged in...
set mode=U
goto start

:start
if "%mode%"=="A" Echo welcome Admin
```

I'm not sure if you understand how the `goto` command works. Anywhere in your program you can put a `:` followed by a word and if you use `goto` followed by that word, you will instantly jump to that point in your program.